# Jinja2 and ansible/python : jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: no filter named 'bool'

Tags: python, filter, ansible, boolean, jinja2

I try to translate this line

```
enabled: "{{ with_postgresql | default(false) | bool }}"
```

with jinja2 library code :

```
template = env.get_template(file)
```

But the result is KO and the error message is :

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: no filter named 'bool'
```

I need to import sometinhg else ?

Comment: Complete the data(playbook, cat files, commands, errors ...) and make it **minimal-complete-verifiable example** [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: A simple execution code :
    from jinja2 import Template
    
    tm = Template("{{ with_packaqge | default(false) | bool }}")
    msg = tm.render(with_packaqge=True)

print(msg)

Comment: the issue is your code example doesn't call an environment and as you figured out, you need to change the env

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to add is line :

```
env.filters['bool']= bool
```

To the Jinja2 environment before calling the `get_template`

```
...
env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FunctionLoader(spit_template))

env.filters['bool']= bool

output = env.get_template('name').render(with_postgresql = 'true')
...
```

I think bool is an ansible functionality.

Comment: an even better option would be using `distutils.util.strtobool`